# What is wrong with this program?

Tags: c, runtime

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    char * a;
    int b[26] = {
        0
    };
    long r = 0;
    scanf("%s", a);
    int j = strlen(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        b[a[i] - 'a'] += 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if ((b[i] / 2) * 2 == b[i])
            r += b[i] / 2;
        else
            r += (b[i] + 1) / 2;
    }
    printf("%ld", r);
    return 0;
}
```

input- 
ssss

this program works fine on my laptop in DEV c++ compiler ..
but when i run it on ideone.com or any other online compiler it gives RUNTIME ERROR ,, please tell me what is the problem with this program

Comment: First decide if this is going to be C or C++ and chose appropriate tags.

Answer (score 5):

You did not allocate memory for `a` and performing operations on that.

Allocate memory for `char* a;`

or You can also take `a` as a **char array** like you did it for `b`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any memory to `a`. Either allocate memory for `char *a` statically by doing `char a[<some_length>];` or do it dynamically by using [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

When ever your giving some thing like this   `char *a;` it means it is a pointer to character type of data. Here, "a" is pointer to the memory location that needs to be allocated.

Allocate memory for the`char *a` something like `a=malloc(20)` or you can directly use array `char a[20]`. It solves your problem.